# Rails model scope with multiple optional associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Deployment, it has following relations:

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user_group, optional: true
```

I want to be able to define scope for easier filtering. I can easily filter by user, something like this:

```
scope :by_owner, -> (ow) {  joins(:user).where("users.name like ?", "%#{ow}%") }
```

But what I really want to use user_group first if association exists and if it doesn't, then fall back on user. Logic would work like this:

```
If this deployment belongs to at least one user_group
  scope :by_owner, -> (ow) {  joins(:user_group).where("user_groups.name like ?", "%#{ow}%") }
else
  scope :by_owner, -> (ow) {  joins(:user).where("users.name like ?", "%#{ow}%") }
end
```

I am guessing that I have to achieve it somehow with an SQL query, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Update
I got a bit closer with the following query:

```
  scope :by_owner, -> (ow) {  joins(:user, :user_group).where("(users.display_name like ?) OR (user_groups.name like ?)", "%#{ow}%", "%#{ow}%") }
```

But it's still not it because 1st of all the records that don't have user_groups association are ignored in the response and also it searches by user even if user_group is defined. Still looking for suggestions if there are any.

Comment: You can create a method that checks the association and if it exists then use the 'user_group' in your scope otherwise use the 'user' in your scope.

Comment: @ZainNazirButt So Rails is going to execute that function for every item in the collection when it determines scope? That's cool, I'll try it out. Thanks!